# asyncio: how to handle exceptions

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm using `asyncio.gather()` to run concurrently two coroutines. They should run forever, so if one of them returns (correctly or with an exception) I'd like to know.

If I use `try/except` for `asyncio.gather()`, I can correctly catch the exceptions of coroutines.

The problem is that one coroutine could create and run a new task with `asyncio.create_task()`. In this case, if an exception occurs during this new task, this exception can't be handled in the context of `gather()`.

```
import asyncio

async def coro3():
    raise RuntimeError

async def coro1():
    asyncio.create_task(coro3())
    while True:
        print("coro1")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
async def coro2():
    while True:
        print("coro2")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(coro1(), coro2())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)   # The exception of coro3() can't be handled here

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be using [`Task.add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.add_done_callback) and check if the task has thrown an exception. For example:

```py
import asyncio


async def coro3():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    raise RuntimeError


def callback(task):
    if task.exception():
        print(f"Exception {task.exception()!r} handled!")


async def coro1():
    t = asyncio.create_task(coro3())
    t.add_done_callback(callback)

    while True:
        print("coro1")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def coro2():
    while True:
        print("coro2")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(coro1(), coro2())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
coro1
coro2
coro1
coro2
Exception RuntimeError() handled!
coro1
coro2

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could be a decorator.
For example:

```py
import asyncio
import functools


def handler(coro):
    @functools.wraps(coro)
    async def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return await coro(*args, **kwargs)
        except RuntimeError as e:
            print(f"Exception {e!r} handled!")
    return wrapped

@handler
async def coro3():
    raise RuntimeError

async def coro1():
    asyncio.create_task(coro3())
    while True:
        print("coro1")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
async def coro2():
    while True:
        print("coro2")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(coro1(), coro2())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        
asyncio.run(main())
```

prints

```
coro1
coro2
Exception RuntimeError() handled!
coro1
coro2
```